# Ring homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $R$ and $S$ be rings. If $f : R \rightarrow S$ is a surjective ring homomorphism, then $$\bar{f} : R / \ker(f) \longrightarrow S, x + \ker(f) \longmapsto f(x)$$ is an isomorphism.

1. First, I wanted to show that $\ker(f)$ is an ideal. I let $r \in R$ and $x \in \ker(f)$. Since $f$ is a homomorphism, we have $$f(rx)=f(r)f(x)=f(r)\cdot 0 = 0$$which means $rx \in \ker(f)$. Similarly, we have$$f(xr)=f(x)f(r)=0 \cdot f(r) = 0$$ which means $xr \in \ker(f)$ as well. Hence, $\ker(f)$ is an ideal, which means $$(x+\ker(f))(y+\ker(f))=xy+\ker(f)$$ and $$(x+\ker(f))+(y+\ker(f))=x+y+\ker(f)$$
2. We have, for multiplication,
   \begin{align}
   \bar{f}((x+\ker(f))(y+\ker(f)))&=\bar{f}(xy+\ker(f))\\
   &=f(xy)\\
   &=f(x)f(y)\\
   &=\bar{f}(x+\ker(f))\bar{f}(y+\ker(f))
   \end{align} 
   and, for addition,
   \begin{align}
   \bar{f}((x+\ker(f))(y+\ker(f)))&=\bar{f}(x+y+\ker(f))\\
   &=f(x+y)\\
   &=f(x)+f(y) \\
   &=\bar{f}(x+\ker(f))+\bar{f}(y+\ker(f))
   \end{align} 
   so $\bar{f}$ is a ring homormorphism.
3. Do I also show that $\bar{f}$ is surjective, so that I have everything I need to establish that $\bar{f}$ is an isomorphism?

Comment: 1. You also need to show $\ker(f)$ is closed under addition. 2. You need to show that $\overline f$ is well-defined, and respects multiplication and addition (and the multiplicative identity). The computation you have displayed accomplishes none of these things; you need to show that $\overline f(xy+\ker(f)) = \overline f(x+\ker(f)) \overline f(y+\ker(f))$.  3. You need to show that $\overline f$ is one-to-one and onto. None of these tasks are particularly difficult, but as you can see, it is a somewhat lengthy laundry list of things to do.

Comment: On the homomorphism part, can I say that $\bar{f}(xy+ker(f)) = f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$?

Comment: Yes, that's essentially the proof that it respects multiplication (maybe with one last equality $=f(x+\ker(f))f(y+\ker(f))$). Well-definedness is important here, though!

Comment: Regarding well-definedness, I have fundamental trouble applying that concept to rings here (and groups as a whole for that matter). All I was informed about a function being well-defined is that for every, say, $x \in D$ (domain $D$) there exists a $y \in f(D)$ such that $f(x)=y$.

Comment: almost - well-definedness is existence *and uniqueness* of such a $y$. Here there are multiple ways of expressing the same input to $f$, so you have to show that if $x+\ker(f)=x'+\ker(f)$, then the definitions for $\overline f(x+\ker(f))$ and $\overline f(x'+\ker(f))$ give the same thing, i.e., that $f(x)=f(x')$. (Here, $x'$ is just another element of R.)

Comment: Okay, so I wrote $$x+\ker(f)=y+\ker(f) \implies \bar{f}(x+\ker(f))=\bar{f}(y+\ker(f)) \implies f(x)=f(y).$$ Does this suffice to show well-definedness?

Comment: The implication "$x+\ker(f)=y+\ker(f) \implies \overline f(x+\ker(f)) = \overline f(y+\ker(f))$ is exactly what you need to show. And no, you haven't shown it here. Hint: use the fact that $x+\ker(f)=y+\ker(f)$ implies $x-y\in \ker(f)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends where you're starting from. If you already know how to make $R/I$ into a ring, where $I$ is an ideal of $R$, the first things you have to show is that $\ker f$ is an ideal and that $\bar{f}$ is well defined. That is:

> if $a+\ker f=b+\ker f$ then $f(a)=f(b)$

Now you want to see that $\bar{f}$ is a ring homomorphism:

> $\bar{f}((a+\ker f)+(b+\ker f))=\bar{f}(a+\ker f)+\bar{f}(b+\ker f)$
>   $\bar{f}((a+\ker f)(b+\ker f))=\bar{f}(a+\ker f)\bar{f}(b+\ker f)$
>   $\bar{f}(1+\ker f)=1$ (if your rings have $1$ and homomorphisms must be unit-preserving)

Then you want to see that $\bar{f}$ is injective, that is

> if $\bar{f}(a+\ker f)=0$ then $a+\ker f=0+\ker f$

Surjectivity is obvious.